# Need to create mutiple circle in a canvas like a paint application

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to create circle when clicking in the circle button,like the circle in paint. Need to draw as many as the user need.

How to work that by using Jquery, HTML5 and CSS3???

I need an application like [this](http://www.cloud-canvas.com/):

Any body know this please help me
And i created event for single circle and that is draggable one. How to add more more images in that section.

```
<script>
function draw_circle() {

 var canvasObj = document.getElementById("mycanvas");

 var canvasCtx = canvasObj.getContext("2d");

 canvasCtx.beginPath();

 canvasCtx.arc(100,100,50,0,Math.PI*2,true);

    var centerX = 288;
    var centerY = 100;
    var radius = 70;


    canvasCtx.fillStyle = "#CB5155";
    canvasCtx.fill();
    canvasCtx.lineWidth = 5;
    canvasCtx.strokeStyle = "black";
    canvasCtx.stroke();

}

    $(function() {
        $( "#mycanvas" ).draggable();
    });


</script>

<canvas id="mycanvas" width="200" height="200"/></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

[jCanvas](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/index.html) jQuery plugin is a potential solution.

```
$('#mycanvas').drawArc({
  fillStyle: '#CB5155',
  x: 288, y: 100,
  radius: 70,
  strokeStyle: 'black',
  lineWidth: 5
});

$('#mycanvas').drawArc({
  fillStyle: '#442299',
  x: 188, y: 70,
  radius: 30,
  strokeStyle: 'blue',
  lineWidth: 2
});
```

That should draw 2 circles on the canvas. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @You-Day - If the answer answers your question it's good practice to mark it as the answer. Not only is it polite, but it will encourage people to answer any other questions you may have.