# How do I append a circle into my <canvas> tag using JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

Can anyone please tell me how to append an image/circle into my `<canvas>` tag using this script?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#pink-circle-button').click(function() {
        $('#currentCircle').css({
            'border': '2px solid rgb(255, 0, 255)', 
            'background-color':'',
            'position': 'fixed',
            'display': 'block',
            'top': '97px', 
            'left': '372px',
            'width': '93px', 
            'height': '90px', 
            'border-radius': '76.5px 76.5px 76.5px 76.5px '
        });

        $( "#currentCircle" ).resizable();
        $("#currentCircle").append();  

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What kind of HTML tag is `#pink-circle-button`? Is it a `<canvas>` element?

Comment: Are you using the jQuery canvas plugin, as suggested on [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175176/need-to-create-mutiple-circle-in-a-canvas-like-a-paint-application)?

Comment: #pink-circle-button is a css id

Comment: — Obviously, but Paul was asking `<WHAT?! id="pink-circle-button">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have some sort of HTML element that you are using CSS borders to render like a circle, in which case:

You can't.

A canvas is a bitmap upon which you can draw. It cannot contain elements (except as a fallback for when canvas is not supported and/or a shadow DOM for non-visual interaction with the element (I'm not sure what the state of the spec and browser support is like for that)).

If you want a circle, then use the [canvas API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/#complex-shapes-paths) to draw one, and don't use that script.

Comment: Thanks for replaying to my question,

Comment: Thanks for your replay Quentin,

If i change the code, Can i able to implement the append function on that. I need to perform, while clicking on the button i need to draw circle, and if i click again i need the same application.. According to the click of the user circle have to be displayed.

And i need to perform drag and drop, Resize and scaling function on that. So how can i do that

Comment: You can't use the append method, it is a jQuery method for modifying the DOM. You don't want to use DOM beyond getting a reference to the cavas object. If you use canvas for this, then you need to do everything in canvas. For what you want to do (unless some other factor means that canvas is better for you), you'd probably be better off with SVG (and VML for old IE). [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) is a decent abstraction library for that.

Comment: Can i use div instead of canvas

Comment: That depends on if you need to use any canvas methods or not.

Comment: canvas is an optional one. but i need the functionality

Comment: Can u please check my next question and try to help me